# Make Google Search app use Google.com.au

Tags: applications, htc-desire, localization, google-search

I purchased my HTC Desire (2.2 FroYo) from the UK and by default I guess the Google Search app uses Google.co.uk whenever I run a search through the app.

This is quite annoying as you could imagine since none of the local services/locations are show since it's searching on the UK domain.

Is there a way **without rooting** that this could be modified?

Comment: Added tag google-search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out a while back that it's my phones locale that is affecting this but never really thought I could change it.

This morning however as I was doing a Goolge search for "how to change Android locale" I though about trying to search for an app on the Market.

Sure enough there are a few that can. The one that I've gone with is made by [inKa](http://www.appbrain.com/browse/dev/inKa).

[Custom Locale](http://www.appbrain.com/app/custom-locale/com.mhoffs.customlocale)

[image: Custom Locale QR Code]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it fit exactly your question, but it may be help:

- Open the web browser, and go to http://www.google.com
- Go to the footer an follow the link `Settings`
- Consider to check `yes` at the question `Allow use of device location?`
- Then follow the link at the top right `More setting >>`
- Finally, set your languages preferences

Comment: I already have these settings on and it still doesn't help. The Google Search app must obtain some sort of information from my phone which lets it know it is from the UK and therefore the results are UK based.

Comment: Ok... The last think I see, try to give it the citizenship, maybe it'll help! (http://www.citizenship.gov.au/should_become/) --- (sorry, just kidding, I'll try again to look at your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick? `Menu > More > Settings > Set home page`

Comment: Unfortunately this will only set my homepage on my browser but the search will still prefer UK results.