# Can I install additional language support (Russian) on HTC Desire HD without rooting?

Tags: htc-desire-hd, localization

I bought HTC Desire HD and I want to change UI language to Russian. The issue is that I see in settings only English, German, Italian and French.

Is it possible to add other language without rooting phone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the same app that I found for my [problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/make-google-search-app-use-google-com-au) to fix yours:

[Custom Locale](http://www.appbrain.com/app/custom-locale/com.mhoffs.customlocale)

[image: Custom Locale QR Code]

Just install it and then select Russian as your predefined language and you're good to go mate.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, after I installed russian SIM-card and performed factory reset, phone automatically started with russian localisation. My wife is happy now.

Comment: After change custom locale, if it also change the phone language ? Such as custom locale change to Russian, if also phone language also change to Russian ?

Answer (score 3):

uthark,

You can try using [MoreLocale2](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&feature=search_result), for an easy locale change.

Answer (score 0):

I have added my language using morelocale2..

Language : ta (Tamil)
Country  : IN (India)

ta_IN

I am able to add and select my language. But, It is not changing the default language of the device.. Still i could it see the things in english .. any suggestions?

Comment: While the first part of this answers the original poster's question, the remainder should be submitted as a new question.