# How can I change the language on my phone?

Tags: languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set the locale and language?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/how-can-i-set-the-locale-and-language)

Is there some way I can change the language of my phone's operating system? I mean status bar, options, everything -- I want it to be in Spanish.

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5303/1465

Answer (score 2):

On the Nexus S go to Menu -> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Language.