# Is it possible to change the system language to Japanese?

Tags: languages, system

I was wondering if it is possible to install Japanese as a System Language on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S2). My friend is from Japan and wants to buy her smartphone in Europe - but she wants to change the system language to Japanese.

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, what is the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I set the locale and language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/how-can-i-set-the-locale-and-language), [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language)

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy SIII also has this problem. When I go to `Settings -> My device -> Language and input`, it is not possible to select Japanese, neither under `Language`, nor under `Samsung keyboard`.