# Can I install the Sinhala language without rooting my android device?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, languages, localization, asus-zenfone-5

I have an Android device which is running Android version 4.3, but when I'm using web browsing, Facebook, Twitter, etc., I can't see any of the content in the Sinhala language.

I found out that there are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Without root Device (Using Font Optimizer App)
2. By rooting the Device

I'm not interested with any of the above solutions since the 1st solution font style is filthy and due to the 2nd solution I'll face many problems such as warranty, updates, etc.

So I'm looking for a way that I can install the Sinhala font without rooting the device. I found this question which is similar to my problem,

- [Can I install additional language support (Russian) on HTC Desire HD without rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5303)

Any suggestion or solution highly appreciated, since this is one of burning question of Sri Lankans.

Comment: We've tried to clean up your question, but you seem to be referring to some links that aren't fully complete in your question. You should fix those up.

Comment: @AlE.thank you for your interest, 
Actually I want a way that can install Sinhala Language font pack without root my device, any suggestion highly appreciate